# GraphFrames: Merge edge nodes with similar column values

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, graph, pyspark, graphframes

tl;dr: How do you simplify a graph, removing edge nodes with identical `name` values?

I have a graph defined as follows:

```
import graphframes
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
vertices = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('1', 'foo', '1'),
    ('2', 'bar', '2'),
    ('3', 'bar', '3'),
    ('4', 'bar', '5'),
    ('5', 'baz', '9'),
    ('6', 'blah', '1'),
    ('7', 'blah', '2'),
    ('8', 'blah', '3')
], ['id', 'name', 'value'])

edges = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('1', '2'),
    ('1', '3'),
    ('1', '4'),
    ('1', '5'),
    ('5', '6'),
    ('5', '7'),
    ('5', '8')
], ['src', 'dst'])

f = graphframes.GraphFrame(vertices, edges)
```

Which produces a graph that looks like this (where the numbers represent the vertex ID): [image: graph]

Starting from vertex ID equal to `1`, I'd like to simplify the graph. Such that nodes with similar `name` values are coalesced into a single node. A resulting graph would look something
like this:

[image: graph]

Notice how we only have one `foo` (ID 1), one `bar` (ID 2), one `baz` (ID 5) and one `blah` (ID 6). The `value` of the vertex is irrelevant, and just to show that each vertex is unique.

I attempted to implement a solution, however it is hacky, extremely inefficient and I'm certain there is a better way (I also don't think it works):

```
f = graphframes.GraphFrame(vertices, edges)

# Get the out degrees for our nodes. Nodes that do not appear in
# this dataframe have zero out degrees.
outs = f.outDegrees

# Merge this with our nodes.
vertices = f.vertices
vertices = f.vertices.join(outs, outs.id == vertices.id, 'left').select(vertices.id, 'name', 'value', 'outDegree')
vertices.show()

# Create a new graph with our out degree nodes.
f = graphframes.GraphFrame(vertices, edges)

# Find paths to all edge vertices from our vertex ID = 1
# Can we make this one operation instead of two??? What if we have more than two hops?
one_hop = f.find('(a)-[e]->(b)').filter('b.outDegree is null').filter('a.id == "1"')
one_hop.show()

two_hop = f.find('(a)-[e1]->(b); (b)-[e2]->(c)').filter('c.outDegree is null').filter('a.id == "1"')
two_hop.show()

# Super ugly, but union the vertices from the `one_hop` and `two_hop` above, and unique
# on the name.
vertices = one_hop.select('a.*').union(one_hop.select('b.*'))
vertices = vertices.union(two_hop.select('a.*').union(two_hop.select('b.*').union(two_hop.select('c.*'))))
vertices = vertices.dropDuplicates(['name'])
vertices.show()

# Do the same for the edges
edges = two_hop.select('e1.*').union(two_hop.select('e2.*')).union(one_hop.select('e.*')).distinct()

# We need to ensure that we have the respective nodes from our edges. We do this  by
# Ensuring the referenced vertex ID is in our `vertices` in both the `src` and the `dst`
# columns - This does NOT seem to work as I'd expect!
edges = edges.join(vertices, vertices.id == edges.src, "left").select("src", "dst")
edges = edges.join(vertices, vertices.id == edges.dst, "left").select("src", "dst")
edges.show()
```

Is there an easier way to remove nodes (and their corresponding edges) so that edge nodes are uniqued on their `name`?

Comment: any rule for selecting one vx from a set, i.e why 2, 3, 4 -> 2; 6, 7, 8 -> 6 ?

Comment: No rule, it was a random selection. The important bit is that the node `name` are unique. The `id` and `value` are largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply treat the `name` column as new `id`?

```py
import graphframes

vertices = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('1', 'foo', '1'),
    ('2', 'bar', '2'),
    ('3', 'bar', '3'),
    ('4', 'bar', '5'),
    ('5', 'baz', '9'),
    ('6', 'blah', '1'),
    ('7', 'blah', '2'),
    ('8', 'blah', '3')
], ['id', 'name', 'value'])

edges = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('1', '2'),
    ('1', '3'),
    ('1', '4'),
    ('1', '5'),
    ('5', '6'),
    ('5', '7'),
    ('5', '8')
], ['src', 'dst'])

#create a dataframe with only one column
new_vertices = vertices.select(vertices.name.alias('id')).distinct()

#replace the src ids with the name column
new_edges = edges.join(vertices, edges.src == vertices.id, 'left')
new_edges = new_edges.select(new_edges.dst, new_edges.name.alias('src'))

#replace the dst ids with the name column
new_edges = new_edges.join(vertices, new_edges.dst == vertices.id, 'left')
new_edges = new_edges.select(new_edges.src, new_edges.name.alias('dst'))

#drop duplicate edges
new_edges = new_edges.dropDuplicates(['src', 'dst'])

new_edges.show()
new_vertices.show()

f = graphframes.GraphFrame(new_vertices, new_edges)
```

Output:

```
+---+----+
|src| dst|
+---+----+
|foo| baz|
|foo| bar|
|baz|blah|
+---+----+

+----+
|  id|
+----+
|blah|
| bar|
| foo|
| baz|
+----+
```

[image: graph]